# Display None Conditional JavaScript Error

Tags: javascript

I have the following script that works when I use it in Google Console, but when I implement the custom script live, it will display: none; the class regardless of the conditions.

```
let notes = document.querySelectorAll(".elementor-element-befe370")[0];
let dents = document.querySelectorAll("elementor-element-1b86ce2");
dents.forEach; {
    if (document.body.textContent.includes("No, +1")) {
      notes.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      notes.style.display = "block";
    }
};
```

If the *dents* text contains "No, +1" then I am looking to remove the *notes* element

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your code is incorrect. The for each loop takes in a function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

```
let notes = document.querySelectorAll(".elementor-element-befe370")[0];
let dents = document.querySelectorAll("elementor-element-1b86ce2");
dents.forEach((dent) => {
    if (dent.textContent.includes("No, +1")) {
      notes.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      notes.style.display = "block";
    }
})
```